# How to define a temporary local variable in jags?

Tags: jags

I want to create a temp variable in jags, but it doesn't work as it would work in R

```
for (cid in 1:CAMPAIGN_N) {
  for (time in 1:DATE_N){      
    index <- time * CAMPAIGN_N + cid - 2
    positives[index] ~ dbin( k[time]*ctr[cid], tries[index])
  }
}
```

Gives error, because `index` variable is being defined only once. So I had to write it the following ugly way:

```
for (cid in 1:CAMPAIGN_N) {
  for (time in 1:DATE_N){      
    positives[time * CAMPAIGN_N + cid - 2] 
      ~ dbin( k[time]*ctr[cid], tries[time * CAMPAIGN_N + cid - 2])
  }
}
```

Is there a way I can create temp variable in jags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to let `index` vary with `time` and `cid`.

```
index[time,cid] <- time * CAMPAIGN_N + cid - 2
positives[index[time,cid]] ~ dbin( k[time]*ctr[cid], tries[index[time,cid]])
```