# JAGS Detection Simulation Error/Ecologists Bungle Advanced Statistics

Tags: r, distribution, jags

I'm brand new to the Bayesian world and excited to apply it to my research. As  a first step I've attempted to build a simulation model that estimates the mean number of animals within a 10km radius of an acoustic detector and detection probability as a function of noise level. Basically, I'm asking if there are 1k animals at two locations but the noise characteristics are different, can the model tell me whether the "true" means (1k animals) are the same between the two study areas. Hopefully, yes.

This is a three step process which relates the number of calls detected (kk1) to detection probability (Pdet) to the signal to noise ratio (SNR, on a log scale) finally to the mean number of animals in the area.

I've simulated my animal locations, source levels, transmission loss (dependent on animal location), SNR and Pdet functions as follows.

```
##################################################################
library(runjags)
#library(plotrix)
library(rjags)

# Initializations, thanks Matt
### Gamma distribution specification function, thanks Matt! ###
gammaPr<-function(mu, sd)
{
  shape<-mu^2/sd^2
  rate<-mu/sd^2
  x<-seq(max(0, mu-4*sd),mu+4*sd, length.out=100)
  #plot(x, dgamma(x, shape=shape, rate=rate), main=paste("Prior distribution with mean ",mu," and sd ", sd), type="l")
  #print(paste("The two parameters of the Gamma distribution are shape=",shape," and rate=",rate))
  return(c(shape,rate))
}

##################
# Simulated Data #
##################

# Number of animals within the detection radius (5km)
N=1000
#x=seq(0,5,by=1/N)



 # Idiot checking:
        # Since this is point sampling and (for the moment) we assume that the number
        # of animals available to be detected increases linearly with radius
    #x1 =    rbeta(N, shape1 = 2, shape2 = 1)
    #theta = runif(N, min = 0, max=2*pi)
    #radial.plot(lengths = x1, radial.pos = theta, rp.type = 's')

## We know the parameters for Source Levels values from the literature
nlpr=gammaPr(120, 30)

# Time series
tt=seq(1, 300, by=1)

# Number of animals at each site available to be sampled
N1=numeric(length=length(tt))
N2=N1
NL1=N1 # Noise Level Distribution
NL2=N1
TL1=N1 # Estimated Transmission loss
TL2=N1
kk1=N1 # Number of animals detected by the sensor 
kk2=N1

for (ii in 1:length(tt)){
  #N1[ii]=round(rnorm(1, mean = 700, sd=100)) # Screw it-there are enough problems to deal with
  #N2[ii]=round(rnorm(1, mean = 700, sd=100)) 
  N1[ii]=1000
  N2[ii]=1000

  # Random whale distances

  r1=rbeta(N1[ii], shape1 = 2, shape2 = 1)*5 # assumed (known)
  r2=rbeta(N2[ii], shape1 = 2, shape2 = 1)*5 


  # Random source levels for each whale
  slpr=gammaPr(131, 20)                     # assumed (known)
  SL1=rgamma(N1[ii], slpr[1], slpr[2])
  SL2=rgamma(N2[ii], slpr[1], slpr[2])

  # Noise Levels for each sensor
  nlpr=gammaPr(120, 30)
  NL1[ii]=rgamma(1, nlpr[1], nlpr[2])      # measured (known)

  nlpr=gammaPr(90, 30)
  NL2[ii]=rgamma(1, nlpr[1], nlpr[2])

  # TL Transmission loss from each animal to sensor
  TL1=20*log10(r1*1000)                   # this one is tricky, we can assume TL but it's based on multiple captures so how this make it into the probability density function escapes me 
  TL2=20*log10(r2*1000)                   

  # Signal to noise ratio for each animal call
  SNR1=SL1-(1/(1000*r1)^2)-NL1[ii]        # calculated
  SNR2=SL2-(1/(1000*r2)^2)-NL2[ii]

  # Detection probability for a given SNR threshold
  Pdet1=pbeta(SNR1, shape1  = 1.5, shape2 = 2.5)  # unknown, we will need to estimate shape1 and shape from the JAGS model
  Pdet2=pbeta(SNR2, shape1  = 1.2, shape2 = 2.5)
  ## Idiot checking again
    #yy=pbeta(seq(-40,40, by=.01), 1.5, 2.5)
    #plot(seq(-40,40, by=.01),yy, xlim=c(-2,2))


  # Number of animals detected is binomial based on the detection function
  kk1[ii]=sum(rbinom(N1[ii], size=1, prob = Pdet1))
  kk2[ii]=sum(rbinom(N2[ii], size=1, prob =  Pdet2))
}

data=data.frame(cbind(tt, N1,N2, NL1, NL2,kk1, kk2))
##################################################################
```

That works fine, but I've been unsuccessful in building a JAGS model that
can predict the mean number of animals across time, let alone at the two different study areas. The latest incarnation of the model, which logically makes sense [to me] throws errors regarding redefining node Pdet[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381267/how-to-define-a-temporary-local-variable-in-jags). But since those are the values I'm trying to estimate, it's rather confusing. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Maybe it's an issue with defining temporary varaibles? [E.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381267/how-to-define-a-temporary-local-variable-in-jags)? But that seems somewhat different that my issue since I'm only working with one loop.

Thank you in advance for your time.

```
#############################################################################
# Model Fitting#
#############################################################################

# Build the JAGS model to determine if the true number 
# of animals at each location is different


# We are trying to estimate the mean population size (mu)
# Number of trials (detection periods)
N=nrow(data)

# We guess that the median range of animals within the detection 
# area is 2500 m (will be updated later with propationg modelling)
# This is stupid. There needs to be stochasticity in both values.
MedTL=20*log10(2500)
MedSL=rgamma(1, slpr[1], slpr[2])


# We are trying to estimate the population mean and the 
# detection function parameters
modeltext <- '
model{

  #### liklihood ### 
  for(ii in 1:N){

    # Number of animals detected is distributed by a normal function the total available (mu)
    # and the probability that they are detected(Pdet)
    kk1[ii] ~ dbin(Pdet, mu)

    # Pdet is a beta distribution with parameters estimated from above
    Pdet<-pbeta(SNR[ii], betaPar1, betaPar2)

    # SNR (signal to noise ratio) is the Source Level-Noise Levl-Transmission Loss
    SNR[ii]<-MedSL-MedTL-NL1[ii]

    # SL and RL need stochasticity.....
    }

  ## Priors ###
    # Mu is dependent on how the animals are distributed in space. In this case, 1000. Because that's what I told it to do. 
    mu~dpois(lambda)

  # We know mu must be greater than 0 and poison
  lambda~dgamma(11, .01) # approximately what they should be based on mu 1000, sd 300

  # We will assume we know a bit about the detection function, we will be helpful
  betaPar1 ~ dnorm(1,.3)
  betaPar2 ~ dnorm(2,.3)
}
  #data# kk1, NL1, N, slpr, MedTL, MedSL
  #monitor# betaPar1, betaPar2, mu, pdet
'

# We could just run the model like this:
results1 <- run.jags(modeltext, n.chains=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JAGS model, Pdet is a scalar probability in

```
kk1[ii] ~ dbin(Pdet, mu)
```

but then you assign Pdet to be a beta probability distribution function:

```
Pdet<-pbeta(SNR[ii], betaPar1, betaPar2)
```

Presumably what you actually mean is that Pdet is DRAWN FROM a beta distribution.  This would be

```
Pdet ~ pbeta(SNR[ii], betaPar1, betaPar2)
```

Or alternatively (more consistent with the data that you simulated), you mean that kk1[ii] is the sum of 1000 Bernoulli trials with individual-specific detection probabilites Pdet.  So what you need to do is let kk1[ii] be the sum of a bunch of individual specific bernoulli trials.  In JAGS, your observed data have to be stochastic realizations of some distribution, so you *cannot* write, for example

```
for(ii in 1:300){
for(jj in 1:mu){
kk11[jj] ~ dbern(p[jj])
}
kk1[ii] <- sum(kk11[jj])
}
```

Fortunately for you, JAGS has anticipated your quandry, and has implemented the special observable function dsum() for precisely your purposes.  Check the JAGS manual.

**So in summary,** unless I'm misreading your simulation, what you really need is to loop over time-steps with kk1[ii], but inside that loop you need to loop over individuals, and each individual will need to have its own modeled detection probability in each time-step.  At this point, you might think to ask, "but how is their possibly enough data to model the individual detection probabilities across time-steps?"  The answer is that all you really need to model is the **distribution** of individual detection probabilities across years.  This will be related to the distribution of individual distances from the sensor, the (potentially time-varying) noise characteristics of the system, and so forth.

The good news is that (to a first approximation), **as long as you can simulate the data in R, you can formulate the corresponding model in JAGS**.  Your challenge now is to make sure that the simulation produces the data that you want it to, and then that the JAGS model actually corresponds to the simulation.

**Postscript**
To that end, I want to note one odd difference between the simulation and the model that you may not have intended.  In the simulation, you fix N=1000.  In the model, your prior for mu is a gamma-Poisson mixture. Did you have a reason for doing that? One reason would be if the true quantity of interest is the Poisson parameter lambda, which corresponds to the density of animals in your system, from which N is drawn.  **In that case**, you should incorporate this as part of your data simulation as well: i.e.

```
N <- rpois(1000)
```

and you should monitor lambda (rather than mu) as the primary quantity of interest in the JAGS output.  [You also need to think here about whether N is drawn once and then fixed, or whether it is drawn repeatedly at different time-steps].  **Otherwise**, you might consider a more intuitive prior for mu.

Comment: Hi Jacob, thanks! That was really helpful. I had fixed N to be 1000, just to cut down on the variation. I also simplified the model to estimate occupancy  (Bernoulli distribution) rather than number of animals. Perhaps it will make sense to bin my time series data at some later point to estimate the number of animals or behaviours but, baby steps.